# Consider the element $1+\sqrt[3]{5}$ of $\mathbb{R}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Here are the following questions and my respective answers follow below. I hope you have suggestions or if there are any mistakes I hope you help me fix them.

1. Find irr$(1+\sqrt[3]{5}, \mathbb{Q})$.
2. Find $[\mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt[3]{5}), \mathbb{Q}]$.
3. Find a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt[3]{5})$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}.$
4. Describe the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt[3]{5})$.
5. Find another zero, $\alpha,$ of Irr$(\mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt[3]{5})$.
6. Find $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha).$
7. Is $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt[3]{5})?$ Justify.

For #1: Let $\alpha = 1+\sqrt[3]{5}.$ Then $\alpha -1 = \sqrt[3]{5} \Rightarrow (\alpha-1)^3 = 5 \Rightarrow (\alpha-1)^3 - 5 = 0 \Rightarrow \alpha^3 -3\alpha^2+3\alpha-6 = 0 \Rightarrow 1+\sqrt[3]{5}$ is a zero of the irreducible polynomial $x^3 -3x^2+3x-6 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Hence, irr$(1+\sqrt[3]{5}, \mathbb{Q}) = x^3 -3x^2+3x-6.$

For #2: Since deg$(1+\sqrt[3]{5}, \mathbb{Q}) = 3, ~[\mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt[3]{5}), \mathbb{Q}] = 3$.

For #3: $\{ 1,\alpha, \alpha^2 \} = \{1, 1+\sqrt[3]{5}, (1+\sqrt[3]{5})^2\}$? or is it $\{1, \sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt[3]{25}, \}$? I bet the latter, right?

For #4:  $\{a + b\sqrt[3]{5}+c \sqrt[3]{25} \mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}\}.$ This is based on latter answer for #3.

For #5: We use $(a^3 - b^3) = (a-b)(a^2 + ab + b^2).$ We have $(x-1)^3 - 5 = (x-1)^3 - (\sqrt[3]{5})^3 = [(x-1) - \sqrt[3]{5}][(x-1)^2 + (x-1)(\sqrt[3]{5}) + \sqrt[3]{25}].$ We solve $(x-1)^2 + (x-1)(\sqrt[3]{5}) + \sqrt[3]{25} = 0$ or $x^2 + (\sqrt[3]{5}-2)x + 1 - \sqrt[3]{5} + \sqrt[3]{25}$ using quadratic equation. We have $x = \dfrac{1}{2} \left[-(\sqrt[3]{5} - 2) \pm \sqrt{(\sqrt[3]{5} - 2)^2 - 4(1 - \sqrt[3]{5} + \sqrt[3]{25})}\right]= \dfrac{1}{2} \left[-\sqrt[3]{5} + 2 \pm \sqrt{-3 \sqrt[3]{25}}\right].$ So, say one of the other roots is $\alpha = \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right) \left[-\sqrt[3]{5} + 2 + \sqrt{-3 \sqrt[3]{25}}\right]$.

For #6: A basis for $\mathbb{Q}\left( \alpha \right) = \mathbb{Q}\left( \dfrac{1}{2} \left[-\sqrt[3]{5} + 2 + \sqrt{-3 \sqrt[3]{25}}\right] \right)$ is $\{ 1, \alpha, \alpha^2 \} = \{1,  \dfrac{1}{2} \left[-\sqrt[3]{5} + 2 + \sqrt{-3 \sqrt[3]{25}}\right], \left(  \dfrac{1}{2} \left[-\sqrt[3]{5} + 2 + \sqrt{-3 \sqrt[3]{25}}\right] \right)^2 \}$

For #7: $\mathbb{Q}\left( \dfrac{1}{2} \left[-\sqrt[3]{5} + 2 + \sqrt{-3 \sqrt[3]{25}}\right] \right) \cong \mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt[3]{5})$ because both of them are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/ \langle x^3 -3x^2+3x-6 \rangle$. I found this on my notes but I can't justify my justification, I can't currently I don't remember why both are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/ \langle x^3 -3x^2+3x-6 \rangle$.

Are there any comments? Are there any mistakes or improvements for my solutions?

Comment: For #3 both would work, as you know a vector space may have many sets of basis vectors.

Comment: #1: why is this polynomial irreducible? #5: find *all* zeros, not just one. Is there a non-real root? This would make #7 very easy.

Comment: @egglog Thanks! It's now clear to me.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Thanks!
#1: (??) I'll think of it first. That's just the way our reference "solves" it.

#5: it is stated actually to find just "another" not necessarily all. But is finding "all" of them better? Then I think that's pretty much it? I have only taken one $\alpha$ which was the "+" of the two roots. Then the other root must be the "-" one I previously didn't choose (?). And as I can see, both these "other" roots are non-real.

Comment: it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ because all of its roots are not in $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @DietrichBurde (??)

Comment: Yes, I am back. And you are right. By the rational root theorem the cubic polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: Thank you!! Um, what about your comment in #5?

Comment: The comment in #5 is for #7. A subfield of $\Bbb R$ cannot be isomorphic to $\Bbb Q(a)$, where $a$ is non-real.