# Consider the following extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$: $\mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt[3]{5})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}, i)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, extension-field

**Which of them are separable and which are normal?**

That is the question and my respective answers follow below. I hope you have suggestions or if there are any mistakes I hope you help me fix them.

**Normal**: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}, i)$

(i). irr$(1+\sqrt[3]{5}, \mathbb{Q}) = x^3 -3x^2+3x-6$ has a complex zero $\alpha = \dfrac{1}{2} \left[-\sqrt[3]{5} + 2 + \sqrt{-3 \sqrt[3]{25}}\right]$ (shown in #5 here: [Consider the element $1+\sqrt[3]{5}$ of $\mathbb{R}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4435556/consider-the-element-1-sqrt35-of-mathbbr)) which is not in $\mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt[3]{5}).$ Thus, $\mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt[3]{5})$ is not normal over $\mathbb{Q}.$

(ii).  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}, i)$ is a splitting field for the polynomial $p(x) = (x^2 -7)(x^2+1)$ over $\mathbb{Q}.$ The roots $p(x)$ are $\pm\sqrt{7}, \pm i$ which all belong to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}, i)$. Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}, i)$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}.$

**Separable**: both

(i). irr$(1+\sqrt[3]{5}, \mathbb{Q}) = x^3 -3x^2+3x-6$ has distinct roots in its splitting field $\mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt[3]{5}, i)$ implying that $x^3 -3x^2+3x-6$ is separable. Furthermore, this implies that every element of $\mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt[3]{5})$ is separable over $\mathbb{Q}.$ Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}$: $\mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt[3]{5})$  is separable.

(ii). The polynomial $p(x) = (x^2 -7)(x^2+1)$ has distinct roots. Thus, each of its zeroes is separable over $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}, i)$ is separable.

Are there any comments? Are there any mistakes or can there be any improvements in my solutions? Thank you!

Comment: Note that every field extension of characteristic 0 is seperable, so this notion is interesting only for finite fields.

Comment: yupp! Thanks! I've also used that as an alternate solution. But is the other approach (which I showed in the post) also correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. As a side-note: your proof for the normality of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}, i)$ easily generalizes to show that the compositum of two normal field extensions is again normal. This is a well-known fact on its own, and it often comes in handy to show that a particular field extension is normal.

Comment: For $\mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt[3]{5})$, I would note that $\mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt[3]{5}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$, which makes it clear that the normal closure of this field has to contain a primitive $3$-rd root of unity, which is not contained in the $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$, since this embeds into the real numbers, which do not contain a primitive $3$-rd root of unity.